# Need inputs to process multiline javastack logs in ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to process below logs through ELK stack. I know basics of logstash processing and grok patterns, and able to write grok for individual lines. But not able to understand the overall strategy  to extract some informative information from these logs.

```
Thread #1: t@-1680123584, lwp=22843, ref=0x1b0f8550, session=9F0071A66D89544155D149CCE2453E9A:mx2135649930e123d964:(WebServiceFacade.java:84), ms=0x78714bc0
<Start Stack Trace>
  <1 - ADK Verbose Trace Entry>
  stateless dispatch for invokeClass.bosInterface executing
  Active: 37 minutes  0.00 seconds 
  User:
    ServiceUser1
  Tenant:
    
  Session:
    9F0071A66D89544155D149CCE2453E9A:mx2135649930e123d964:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)
  Parameters:
    bosContext _cntx:
      user:
        ContextUser1
      depth:
        3
      session id:
        9F0071A66D89544155D149CCE2453E9A:mx2135649930e123d964:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)
    bosUTF _className:
      TestClassName1
    bosStringList _construct:
      2 entries
          $$MXRIP$$|java.util.HashMap
          1
    bosUTF _methodName:
      TestMethodName1
    bosStringList _params:
      2 entries
          $$MXRIP$$|java.util.HashMap
          16
    uint8 _local:
      1

  Error Stack:
  
Thread #2: t@-1686439616, lwp=22837, ref=0x1b7a81c0, session=2FF1BFBFCC010E7815678741BB95907F:mx115420087975768b5:(WebServiceFacade.java:84), ms=0x78caa910
<Start Stack Trace>
  <1 - ADK Verbose Trace Entry>
  stateless dispatch for invokeClass.bosInterface executing
  Active: 34 minutes  45.00 seconds 
  User:
    ServiceUser2
  Tenant:
    
  Session:
    2FF1BFBFCC010E7815678741BB95907F:mx115420087975768b5:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)
  Parameters:
    bosContext _cntx:
      user:
        ContextUser2
      depth:
        2
      session id:
        2FF1BFBFCC010E7815678741BB95907F:mx115420087975768b5:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)
    bosUTF _className:
      ClassName2
    bosStringList _construct:
      2 entries
          $$MXRIP$$|java.util.HashMap
          7
    bosUTF _methodName:
      TestMethodName2
    bosStringList _params:
      2 entries
          $$MXRIP$$|java.util.HashMap
          6
    uint8 _local:
      1

 Error Stack:
```

If someone can help me to understand the overall strategy how I can get below information from these logs like:
For Thread1:

```
Active => 37 minutes  0.00 seconds
User => ServiceUser1
Tenant => 
Session => 9F0071A66D89544155D149CCE2453E9A:mx2135649930e123d964:(WebServiceFacade.java:84)
Parameters:
user => ContextUser1
bosUTF _className => TestClassName1
bosUTF _methodName => TestMethodName1
```

And similar information for next threads which will be in same log file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand multiline parsing for separating each thread as one log event

```
input{
    file{
        path => "/home/test_logs.log"
        tags => ["samplelog"]
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
                pattern => "^\s"
                negate => true
                what => "previous"
        }

    }

}
```

Then you will be proceeding with the filteration

```
filter{

  if "samplelog" in [tag]{

        grok{

         break_on_match => false

         #log parsing

         match => { "message" => "<grok pattern here>"}

        }
        
        #For possibly using the date from log
        date{

         match => ["Timestamp", "UNIX_MS"]

         target => "@time"

        }

     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I already have similar logstash.conf file, but the problem is in my log files there are numerous spaces and new line characters between values and putting all those in grok pattern is really messy.

Comment: So you need to get the proper log pattern?

Comment: (?<message>(.|\r|\n)*)Active: %{GREEDYDATA:Active}\n.*User:\n(?<User>(.|\r|\n)*)Tenant:\n(?<Tenant>(.|\r|\n)*)Session:\n(?<Session>(.|\r|\n)*)Parameters:\n%{GREEDYDATA:param1}\n.*user:\n(?<user>(.|\r|\n)*)\n.*depth:\n(?<depth>(.|\r|\n)*)\n.*session id:\n(?<session id>(.|\r|\n)*)\)\n.*bosUTF\s_className:\n(?<bosUTF _className:>(.|\r|\n)*)\n.*bosStringList((.|\r|\n)*)bosUTF\s_methodName.*\n(?<bosUTF _methodName>(.|\r|\n)*)\n.*bosStringList _params.*\n%{GREEDYDATA}

This is a rough try, but this might give you an idea on this.